# Why does an email subject contain linefeed or carriage return characters?

Tags: email, smtp, imap, rfc, linefeed

I'm making a code to check a mailbox, and forward unseen mails to another user.
But sometimes it fails with an error:

> ValueError: Header values may not contain linefeed or carriage return characters

I checked the raw fetched data and found out that the 'Subject' value contains \r\n.
Not all mails contain, but some do.
It just appears normal in the mailbox, and I have no idea why some contain such characters.
Does it have to do with the length of the subject?
How can I deal with these situations?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email messages have a maximum line length. That's historical and the rule isn't upheld 100% of the time, so to speak. But in header fields, a space is to be treated the same as a CR LF and a sequence of spaces or a htab character. This is a really long subject, encoded in that way:

```
Subject: Pretend this is about 80-90
  characters long
```

The simplest way to deal with it is to consider any sequences of space characters to be a single space.

Read the source of any email message, you'll see this wrapping in most of then. The `Received` fields is almost always wrapped, for instance, and quite often `To` if there are many addressees, or `Content-Type`/`Content-Disposition` for attachments.

Comment: Ah, it was about the length. Thanks! If it's okay with you, could you check my another question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61361631/why-are-the-same-contents-decoded-differently-according-to-mail-clients